# php login array issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I set up an array that holds 'username' and 'password' to go through login validation functions and I keep getting the error that 'username' and 'password' is an Undefined index on line 24.

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<?php require_once("redirect.php");
require_once("proj2Functions.php");

$errors = [];
$message = "";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {//1
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim ($_POST["password"]);

    $fieldsRequire = array("username", "password");
    foreach($fieldsRequire as $field) {//2
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if (!has_presence($value)) {//3
            $errors[$field] = ucfirst($field) . " can't be blank"; 
        }//3
    }//2
    $fieldsMax = 5;
    foreach($fieldsRequire as $fieldm) {//4
        $value = trim($_POST[$fieldm]);
        if (!has_max_length($value, $fieldsMax)) {//5
            //Line 24
            $errors[$fieldm] .= "<br>- can't be more then {$fieldsMax}       characters.";
        }//5
    }//4 

    foreach($fieldsRequire as $FIELD) {
        $value1 = trim($_POST[$FIELD]);
        if (!specialChar($value1)) {
            $errors[$FIELD] .= "<br>- cannot have a $ sign.";
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {//6
        if ($username == "zach" && $password == "zach") {//7
            redirect_to("Homepage2.php"); 
        } else { 
            $message = "Username/password do not match.";
        }//8
    }//6
}else {
    $username = "";
    $message = "Please log in.";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Start Collay Login(beginLogin)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <?php echo formErrors($errors); ?>
        <?php print_r($_POST); ?>

        <form action="beginLogin.php" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br>
            Password: <input type="text" name="password" value=""><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never initialised `$error[$fieldm]`.

so when you access it by `$error[$fieldm] .= "..."`, it's the same as
`$error[$fieldm] = $error[$fieldm] + "..."`

and before the first assignment, `$error[$fieldm]` does not exist.

**edit to answer the comment:**

the clean way would be to check if the field exists and if not, initialise it with an empty string:

```
if(!isset($error[$fieldm])) {
    $error[$fieldm] = "";
}
```

so afterwards you can append to it without checking.

the dirty, but working way (not recommended) would be to simply suppress the undefined index-error with the `@`-operator, since in that case PHP assumes an empty string. but, as i said, not recommended. and very, very dirty.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! How can I add the new errors to original array "errors[$field]" ?